# Get face global normal in Three.js

Tags: three.js

Say I have a intersect found using raycaster.

```
intersects[0]
```

How do I get this intersect face's world normal?

Hopefully I have formulated this question correct. 
To put it in another way: 
How do I get the direction of a point on the surface of a mesh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The normal will be available in the face.

For example

```
intersects[0].face.normal
```

A typical intersect returns the following:

```
{
    "distance": 511.4062319788414,
    "point": {
        "x": -49.99999999999999,
        "y": -2.3972604422461297,
        "z": -8.950476224522788
    },
    "face": {
        "a": 2,
        "b": 3,
        "c": 1,
        "normal": {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 0,
            "z": 0
        },
        "vertexNormals": [{
            "x": 1,
            "y": 0,
            "z": 0
        }, {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 0,
            "z": 0
        }, {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 0,
            "z": 0
        }],
        "color": {},
        "vertexColors": [],
        "vertexTangents": [],
        "materialIndex": 0
    },
    "faceIndex": 1,
    "object": {
        "metadata": {
            "version": 4.3,
            "type": "Object",
            "generator": "ObjectExporter"
        },
        "geometries": [{
            "uuid": "D12DB865-0BA3-4B38-BB18-92CBCFD5D630",
            "type": "BoxGeometry",
            "width": 20,
            "height": 20,
            "depth": 20
        }],
        "materials": [{
            "uuid": "B405897C-0A60-44A8-B057-683EFA53E895",
            "type": "MeshLambertMaterial",
            "color": 16716340,
            "ambient": 16777215,
            "emissive": 0
        }],
        "object": {
            "uuid": "34E07648-DA46-42B8-A1B1-7C87A67315B9",
            "type": "Mesh",
            "name": "cube1",
            "geometry": "D12DB865-0BA3-4B38-BB18-92CBCFD5D630",
            "material": "B405897C-0A60-44A8-B057-683EFA53E895",
            "matrix": [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -60, 0, 0, 1]
        }
    }
}
```

To convert to world Normal, where object is the picked item, use

```
var normalMatrix = new THREE.Matrix3().getNormalMatrix( object.matrixWorld );
console.log(normal.clone().applyMatrix3( normalMatrix ).normalize());
```

Comment: How do I do this for a nested object?

Comment: @JamesHeald Your question is tangentially related to OP. However, when using the raycaster, there is the commonly used method: .intersectObject ( object, recursive ). The second parameter "recursive" needs to be set to true to recurse through all nested objects. This can have affects on performance and needs to be well considered.

Comment: @JamesHeald it just dawned on me that you were asking a different question: How does one convert the local normal to world normal? the code snippet at the bottom of my original answer will convert the local normal to a world normal.

Comment: @Radio thanks! Thats exactly what I needed. Sorry if that was already there, I might have missed it.